# Сохранение файла в tkinter

Tags: python, изображения, tkinter, save

Имеется функция в классе:

```
def save(self):
    filename = "temp.jpg"
    self.image.save(filename)
```

как не меняя ее структуры сделать сохранение с заданным размером (28 x 28 px)?

Answer (score 1):

***Заранее прошу прощения, если написал бесполезную ерунду!!***

Может мой ответ неправильный, но как я помню можно работать только с .gif изображениями, если не установлена какая-то библиотека

[Конвертировать изображение в .gif и всякие прикольные функции](https://image.online-convert.com/ru/convert-to-gif)

[просто изменить размер изображения](https://www.imgonline.com.ua/resize-image.php)

Вот мой кусок кода, когда хотел, чтоб вместо обычной кнопки была кнопка с картинкой. Размер остается такой же как и картинки.

```
class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super(Main, self).__init__(root)
        self.init_main()

    def init_main(self):
        toolbar = tk.Frame(bg='#d7d8e0', bd=2)
        toolbar.pack(side=tk.TOP, fill=tk.X)

        self.add_img = tk.PhotoImage(file="H:/Disk_H/Downloads/My directory/Python/exe/triangle/buttonfree.gif")
        btn_open_dialog = tk.Button(toolbar, text='condition', command=self.open_dialog, bg='powder blue', bd=0, compound=tk.TOP, image=self.add_img)
        btn_open_dialog.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    def open_dialog(self):
        Child()
```

Comment: Проблему решил, но спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0):

Если кому то в будущем нужно будет,вот реализация

```
def save(self):
    filename = "temp.png"
    self.image.save(filename)
    img = Image.open('temp.png')
    width = 28
    height = 28
    resized_img = img.resize((width, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    resized_img.save('temp.png')
```